# Magento CE 1.7 Trying to create a new EAV for a category option, but installer script is not running

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add some custom options to the categories on our Magento install. I found a way to do this using installer scripts, but my script is not running(I included a die(); call in it for testing). I have also tried changing the version number in core_resource table to 0.1.0 to try and run the upgrade again.

In ~app/code/local/CandS/NewCat/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <CandS_NewCat>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </CandS_NewCat>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <cands_newcat_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>CandS_NewCat</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </setup>
        </cands_newcat_setup>
        <cands_newcat_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_writep</use>
            </connection>
        </cands_newcat_write>
        <cands_newcat_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </cands_newcat_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

And in ~app/code/local/CandS/NewCat/sql/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "banner_image", array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend' => true,
    'frontend' =>true,
    'label' =>'Banner Image',
    'input' => 'text',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required' => false,
    'note' => 'Test note',
    'group'             => 'General Information',
    'sort_order'        => 13
    ));
die("Running Setup");
$installer->endSetup();
```

And finally, app/etc/modules/CandS_NewCat.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CandS_NewCat>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </CandS_NewCat>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sql update file path is wrong-it  should  `app/code/local/CandS/NewCat/sql/cands_newcat_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php`. and you must have  `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`(`if is not exits in /sql/cands_newcat_setup`  ).

Comment: Thank you so much! I added the folder you mentioned and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use  my extension or you can see **my Previous comment**

config.xml is path- app\code\local\Amit\Categoryattribute\etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Categoryattribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Amit_Categoryattribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <categoryattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amit_Categoryattribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </categoryattribute_setup>
            <categoryattribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </categoryattribute_write>
            <categoryattribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </categoryattribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

sql file path is-app\code\local\Amit\Categoryattribute\sql\categoryattribute_setup\mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'banner_image', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'image',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Banner Image',
    'backend'       => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

module file Amit_Categoryattribute.xml path is 'app\etc\modules\'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Categoryattribute>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Amit_Categoryattribute>
    </modules>
</config>
```